# What is the minimum ceiling and visibility limits in Class E airspace?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace, visual-flight-rules, far-91, class-e-airspace

With the intention of landing, taking off, or entering the traffic pattern at an airport in Class E airspace, what is the minimum ceiling and visibility as a VFR pilot in the USA.

Comment: Can't you easily find that online?

Answer (score 6):

VFR cloud clearance requirements are listed in [14 CFR 91.155](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/074608a2fa18b48a86256eeb006704ef!OpenDocument) and for Class E airspace specifies:

> **Class E:**
>   *Less than 10,000 feet MSL.*
>   Flight Visibility: 3 statute miles
>   Distance From Clouds: 500 feet below, 1,000 feet above, 2,000 feet
>   horizontal.
>
> *At or above 10,000 feet MSL.*
>   Flight Visibility: 5 statute miles
>   Distance From Clouds: 1,000 feet below, 1,000 feet above, 1 statute
>   mile horizontal.

There is also a requirement specific to Class E *surface areas* that says that the ceiling must be *at least* 1,000 feet in order to operate in the airspace.  It is also listed in 91.155:

> (c) Except as provided in Sec. 91.157, no person may operate an
>   aircraft beneath the ceiling under VFR within the lateral boundaries
>   of controlled airspace designated to the surface for an airport when
>   the ceiling is less than 1,000 feet.

Note that there are exceptions for both of these that refer to [91.157 Special VFR Weather Minimums](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/688420e12b4f38e9862576e300703639!OpenDocument) if you are instrument rated and the aircraft is instrument equipped.

Comment: Given a scenario of clouds being at exactly 1,000 ft AGL over a Class E surface area airspace, would it be correct to say that the pilot operating under VFR would have to fly the pattern at no greater than 500 ft AGL to keep cloud clearance per class E requirements?

Comment: @RyanGriffith That's correct!

Comment: That's sure to piss the neighbors off.